# How can we get an equality for the norm?

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $x:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the supremum norm $\displaystyle{\|x\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|x(t)|}$ and $T: C^1[0,1]\rightarrow C[0,1]$ with $T(x)(t)=\int_0^tsx(s)\, ds$.

I want to calculate $\|T\|:=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|T_1(x)\|$.

I have found the following: $$\|T(x)\|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}|T(x)(t)|=\sup_{t\in [0,1]}\left |\int_0^tsx(s)\, ds\right |\leq \sup_{t\in [0,1]}\int_0^t|sx(s)|\, ds \\  =\int_0^1|sx(s)|\, ds=\int_0^1s\cdot |x(s)|\, ds   \leq \int_0^1s\cdot \sup_{\sigma \in [0,1]}{|x(\sigma)|}\, ds=\int_0^1s\cdot \|x\|\, ds$$

And so $$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|T(x)\|\leq \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\int_0^1s\cdot \|x\|\, ds=\int_0^1s\cdot 1\, ds=\left [\frac{s^2}{2}\right ]_0^1=\frac{1}{2}$$

So we have an inequality $\|T\|\leq \frac{1}{2}$. How can we get an equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=1$. Then $\|x\|=1$ and $\bigl\|T(x)\bigr\|=\dfrac12$.

Comment: So, do we not need what I have done?

Comment: Why can we take that $x$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Of course. What you did proves that $\|T\|\leqslant\frac12$ and what I did proves the reverse inequality.

Comment: @MaryStar Why not?

Comment: How do we get the reverse inequality? I got stuck right now.

Comment: Since $\|T\|=\sup\left\{\bigl|T(x)\bigr|\,\middle|\,\|x\|=1\right\}$ and since I proved that $\frac12\in\left\{\bigl|T(x)\bigr|\,\middle|\,\|x\|=1\right\}$, $\|T\|\geqslant\frac12$.

Comment: Ah I see!! Does it hold that $s\cdot \operatorname{Id}_{[0,1]}(s)$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Oh I forgot the second part of the equation. I wanted to ask if it holds that  $s\cdot \operatorname{Id}_{[0,1]}(s)=s$

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it does.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)